# look off of each other's papers during the test

Tags: single-word-requests

Do we have any term for "*look off of each other's papers during the test*" in English? (cheating methods)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply best described as:

***Copying***

at least in AmE

Answer (score -1):

Test-swapping, checking answers with a peer, peeking if it's not allowed by administration then it would be referred to as cheating. So short answer yes.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.